# mypy gets "namespace has no attritube XXX" error on argparse

Tags: python, mypy

I am trying to use `mypy` for type annotation. I wrote a simple `test.py`

```
import argparse

args = None
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--dev', '-d', action='store_true', required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

args.dev = True
```

After I ran `mypy test.py`, I got an error:

> test.py:8: error: "Namespace" has no attribute "dev"

My assumption is that attritubes of Namespace class is dynamically created so they cannot be detected by `mypy`? I am able to get ride of this error message after replacing the last line with `setattr(args, 'dev', True)` but this does not look right... Can someone help me understand this problem? I am using Python 3.6.1.

Comment: It will work once [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/521) is resolved.

Comment: 3 years later and this question is still not answered, but still valid.

Comment: 5 years on, no change.